# RecyclerView's scroll do not work to the bottom

Tags: android, xml, layout, scroll, android-recyclerview

I created app like below

[image]

First Recyclerview(horizontal one) works properly.
However, when I scroll second RecyclerView(vertical one) it doens't work properly. I can't scroll view to the bottom.

Here's my xml code.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.ulimbridge.firechatting.views.ChatFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_approachingUsers"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="다가온 인연"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:fontFamily="@font/nanum_square_r"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    />
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/ApproachingRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.15"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_approachingUsers"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/view_chatMessage"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:background="#72808A"
    android:text="메시지"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:fontFamily="@font/nanum_square_r"
    android:textSize="15sp"

    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ApproachingRecyclerView" />


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/chatListRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_chatMessage"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

I used scrollview or nestedscroll view, but it didn't work.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you want  hide horizontal recyclerview when vertical recyclerview scroll ? Just list Instagram app    horizontal recyclerview(user story) and vertical recyclerview (user post).

Comment: No I don't want. First of all, I want to scroll vertical recyclerview to the bottom.

Comment: I tried to delete horizontal recyclerview, but it didn't work. So, it doesn't depend on whether another recyclerview exists.

Comment: Please write all xml file code,Your written  xml code is  not complete.

Comment: I figured out. I added 'paddingBottom', and then, I can scroll down to the bottom.

Comment: @NikhilVadoliya Thanks for comments.

Comment: For anyone looking for an answer in the future - I had a similar problem and indeed setting a `paddingBottom` is a workaround. However, there is a better solution - make the main layout `LinearLayout` instead of `ConstraintLayout` if it's possible, no strange padding value is needed then.

Comment: Paddingbottom works for me. I used 120dp for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to scroll all the way to the bottom of the RecyclerView list.  I tried the above suggestion about making the main container a vertical linearlayout and that works for me.